# Ruby timeout a block of code after n *milli* seconds

Tags: ruby, timeout

In Ruby, I need to time out the execution of a block of code after n *milli* seconds. I know that the Ruby Timeout library supports timeouts in *seconds*:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/index.html

Is this possible?

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you simply passed a decimal into that method.

Comment: By decimal, Craig means: 0.010, 0.5, etc.

Comment: If you look at the source to timeout you'll see that it just passes the argument to Kernel#sleep, which will take a decimal: "Suspends the current thread for duration seconds (which may be any number, including a Float with fractional seconds)." So passing it a decimal should work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use a decimal value for the timeout. Example for n milliseconds:

```
Timeout::timeout(n / 1000.0) { sleep(100) }
```